# This site can’t be reached - DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: dns, web

I was not able to access GitHub.com on one Mac computer. Neither google chrome or firefox worked. The error message says: This site can’t be reached github.com’s server IP address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not just the dns cache is the problem, the problem is the negative entries. Whenever you try to visit a site, the translated IP address gets stored into DNS cache, both successful and unsuccessful attempts. And your browser, rather querying the dns server, looks at your dns cache and hosts file before going to the website. If the entry is corrupted, then you fail to reach the website. So flushing DNS cache will help you. Also keep your hosts file %windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts can contain invalid IP address and domain name mapping so keep it updated and changed ange dhcp dns to a working one.

Hosts file is the easiest way to map a IP address and domain name. Your browser will first look at the hosts file if the requested website's up address is there. Computers can't understand domain names, they understand ip addresses. And dns does the job. But also if you add an entry in your hosts file, it reduces the time to query into the hierarchy of DNS server. But most websites have dynamic ip addresses and they change frequently. So if the website has changed IP address but your hosts file contains the wrong one, then you will be no longer able to access the website. So to fix this open cmd and run command `nslookup website_domain_name` to get IP address and replace it with the old one.

If you are connected to internet using your isp, then Dynamic host configuration protocol DHCP assigns you TCP/IP settings and also the dns server. But should not use ISP default dns server for speed and privacy reasons. So change it to google or cloudfare public dns (8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1).

Comment: Thanks! Just to add, I used this protocol to flush the DNS cache: https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-clear-dns-cache-on-mac/#Flush

Comment: Thanks working fine